# Maven dependencies for Jetty 9.3+ with JSP support (NOT embedded)

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jetty-9

I'm in the process of upgrading my jetty 9.2 server running some webapp using tanukisoftware wrapper to run on my server. However, the switch to apache-jsp seems to have introduced all sorts of dependency issues. I cannot even render JSP pages any more!

Does anyone have an example, non-embedded JSP Jetty 9.3+ maven project using web.xml and jetty.xml on github that I can use as a reference to get my configuration and dependency settings right?

I'm starting jetty via main class org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main and jetty.xml as the parameter.

TY in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add something like the following to jetty.xml:

```
<Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
</Array>  

<Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.configuration</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <Ref id="plusConfig" />
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Looks like I should migrate to an embedded Jetty because the documentation covers a lot of embedded usage. And programming in XML isn't that attractive anyways...